# How to display a specific size image using SRCSET no matter what the device's pixel ratio is?

Tags: html, responsive-design, retina-display, srcset, responsive-images

I am using `srcset` to display an animated GIF for users on large devices, but need to display a static JPG to users on small and medium devices.

The following code works great when I resize my browser window on a 1x screen. The issue I'm running into is when viewing the page on iPad in portrait mode (768px), the animated GIF is displaying. I get that the browser is trying to display a higher quality image, since it's a 2x resolution, but in my case, it needs to be an entirely different image.

How can this be changed to only show the GIF if the user's screen is wider than 940px?

```
<img src="static.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 940px)" srcset="static.jpg 940w, animated.gif 1400w" alt="">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a job for `srcset` at all - `srcset` handles multiple sources that are all exactly identical except for resolution.  If you're providing *different* images, use `<picture>` and multiple `<source>` elements.

For example, to answer your question precisely as asked:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 940px)" srcset="animated.gif">
  <img src="static.jpg">
</picture>
```

But the meta-question remains: why are you only sending the gif to large-screen devices?  Are you imagining that large-screen devices have more bandwidth or something?

Comment: You guessed correct. The animated GIFs can be up to 4 MBs, so we're serving mobile users JPEGs that are _much_ smaller in file size.